# SQL Server: Convert varchar to decimal (with considering exponential notation as well)

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, type-conversion

I need to convert data of a table and do some manipulation.

One of the column datatypes is `Varchar`, but it stores **decimal** numbers.
I am struggling to convert the `varchar` into `decimal`.

I have tried `CAST( @TempPercent1  AS DECIMAL(28, 16))`

Problem is that data also has some values in exponential notation, for example: `1.61022e-016`.

The sql query is throwing error on encountering such value.
The error is `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

How should I handle exponential notation values during varchar to decimal conversion?

Comment: Is this a good lesson? Don't store numbers as strings in the first place?

Comment: I agree that numbers should be stored as numbers and not strings. But I am doing data migration, and source data is not in my control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try following, but you may loose accuracy:

```
select cast(cast('1.61022e-016' AS float) as DECIMAL(28, 16))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could just do

```
CAST(CAST(value AS float) AS decimal(36, 20))
```

**but...**

If you do that, the cast-to-float will also change all values that have no E inside - because floats can only be as exact as the machine-epsilon ...

You can mitigate that, by only casting to float if the number contains an E (+/-). 
If it's a normal decimal number, just cast to decimal directly. 
This will minimize float-round-off errors.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN factor LIKE '%E-%' THEN CAST(CAST(factor AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(36, 20)) 
        WHEN factor LIKE '%E+%' THEN CAST(CAST(factor AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(36, 20)) 
        ELSE CAST(factor AS DECIMAL(36, 20)) 
    END AS factor
FROM T_IFC_Import_Currency
```

Or more compact:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN factor LIKE '%E[+-]%' THEN CAST(CAST(factor AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(36, 20)) 
        ELSE CAST(factor AS DECIMAL(36, 20)) 
    END AS factor
FROM T_IFC_Import_Currency
```

**Note:**
Don't simplify this to:

```
SELECT
    CAST
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN factor LIKE '%E[+-]%' THEN CAST(factor AS FLOAT) 
            ELSE factor 
        END
        AS decimal(36,20) 
    ) AS factor 
FROM T_IFC_Import_Currency
```

because that means the case expression is first implicitly cast to float before it is being cast to decimal...

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(Decimal(28,16),convert(float,'1.61022e-016'))
```