# Convert from varchar to decimal without precision loss

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm working with a table that contains numeric data with decimals stored as VARCHAR. These numbers have an unpredictable number of decimals (up to 10 I believe) but they can also come in scientific notation ('1231E-03')

I've been trying different workarounds to deal with them (like what is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18452603/5866637)

I have no issues converting regular decimal numbers, but when dealing with the exponential notation I'm unable to get rid of the floating point precision issues.

```sql
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(MAX) = '123456789.123e-5'
SELECT CONVERT(Decimal(38,18), CONVERT(float, @Value))
```

Will be resolved as

```
1234.567891229999986535
```

Is it possible to do any transformation so I can convert the number above to the decimal

```
1234.567891230000000000
```

I've tried concatenating a bunch of zeroes to the number but when I have to do the casting to float, it eats all those extra zeroes.

The other thing I've tried is to reduce the precision of my decimal values. If I use `Decimal(38,13)` I get the expected value but, could that cause issues? If I know that I will never get a value in the database with more than 13 decimal points, is it safe to use convert to (38,13) or shall I pursue a different workaround?

Any help would be appreciated and sorry if this is considered duplicate, but the closest match I found is the link above and it was formulated 6 years ago.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://rextester.com/AXMF22856)

Comment: Sami, on real SQL Server 2017 it is reproducible.

Comment: To be more specific, this is an Azure SQL managed instance. Updated tags to clarify. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Not repoducable on SQL Server 2008 R2 (returns `1234.567891230000000000`). Notice that CONVERT to FLOAT returns correct `1234.56789123` on SQL Server 2017 too. This is probably a bug (or a feature) of FLOAT to DECIMAL conversion, for scale above 13 as `SELECT CONVERT(Decimal(38,13),  CONVERT(float, @Value))` works as expected on SQL Server 2017 too.

Comment: I observe similar behaviour to @wqw: SQL Server 2014 Dev - always returns correct values; SQL Server 2016 Std - scale above 13 causes issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql)

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(MAX) = '123456789.123e-5'
SELECT round(CONVERT(Decimal(38,18), CONVERT(float, @Value)), 8)
```

Comment: Good answer.  Curiously enough it breaks when you round to 14+  +1

Comment: Is it possible to pass the rounding amount dynamically calculated? Your solution would work for a number with 8 significant digits, but if it has more than 8 relevant digits? I.e. `'123456789.123456789e-3'` it rounds to `123456.789123460000000000`

Comment: You might be able to do some math to get a number and pass it in as the 2nd param to `round` but why would you at that point? I would either round or not round based on the situation in which you need to use the value and not base that decision on the value itself. @Narshe

Comment: I would like to avoid rounding. My hope is that it could work the same way that it works for non E values, where the convert returns the exact same number as written on text.